# Weird netlogo behavoir with big agentset and matrix extension

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I’m running a netlogo model with around 120000 turtles. At some point while the program is running, netlogo is changing one entry of a matrix to negative value. It is always happening at the same entry but the time and value differ. Normally nothing should be changed in this matrix and when I am running the program with a reduced Agentset, for example with 100000 turtles, everything works fine and the matrix is not changed.

Does anyone know why this is happening and probably has an answer to this issue?

Hi everyone,
This is the code snippet where the failure occurs:

```
                    set mxH2_seg1_tpa matrix:times-element-wise mx_seg1_tpa mxH1_av 
                    set mxH2_seg1_tpb matrix:times-element-wise mx_seg1_tpb mxH1_av
                    set mxH2_r_seg1_tp matrix:times-element-wise mx_r_seg1_tp mxH1_av 

                    set row 0
                    set column 0          ;At this point everything is fine           
                    while [row <= 9][
                      while [column <= 24][
                        if matrix:get mxH2_seg1_tpa column row != 0 [matrix:set mxH_seg1_tpa column row (ln matrix:get mxH2_seg1_tpa column row)] 
                        if matrix:get mxH2_seg1_tpb column row != 0 [matrix:set mxH_seg1_tpb column row (ln matrix:get mxH2_seg1_tpb column row)]     

                   ;After here matrix mx_r_seg1_tp is changed and partly filled with strange values

                        if matrix:get mxH2_r_seg1_tp column row != 0 [matrix:set mxH_r_seg1_tp column row (ln matrix:get mxH2_r_seg1_tp column row)]
                        set column column + 1]
                      set column 0
                      set row row + 1]
```

The complete code is already very long so if the mistake is somewhere there I need some advice what to look for.

Comment: Wow, that is super weird. Would you post your code?

Comment: I added a code snippet in my question. Hopefully it already helps understanding the problem.

Comment: The comment in the code says that `mx_r_seg1_tp` is changed, but the next line sets an element of `mxH_r_seg1_tp`.  Is there a typo in the comment? Did you mean to add an "H"?

Comment: No it is not a typo in the comment. It is matrix `mx_r_seg1_tp` which is changed.

Comment: So `mx_r_seg1_tp` is OK before the third `if` in the inner `while` loop, but after that line, it's been altered, even though nothing in that line writes (or reads) `mx_r_seg1_tp`?  If that's really what's happening, @BryanHead's comment would be entirely correct.  Maybe a bug in the matrix extension or NetLogo itself?  (Or java???)  No matrix element should be altered by code that doesn't reference it.

Comment: Yes, that is happening. Are there any limitations known to the matrix extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the complete code I found my mistake. At one specific point I forgot to use `matrix:copy`. I am still not sure how the size of the agentset is influencing this problem but I do not think it is some kind of implementation bug. Thank you very much for your support. Your tips helped me to find my mistake. So if anyone has a similar problem, check if `matrix:copy` was used appropriately. Cheers Jan

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the random seed (to any number). Then run your simulation and see when it fails and which turtle etc. Then run it again and stop it at the tick before failure and print out the variables and inspect the turtle that is about to cause the failure.

Comment: Hi JenB, thanks for your answer. I managed to run the simulation into the error at always the same turtle with your advice. But it is not the turtle itself causing this issue. When deleting this specific turtle the error occurs with another turtle. Both turtle does not have anything in common.

Comment: No, it won't be anything to do with the turtle. The point of doing this is to stop the simulation just before it fails and look at the parameter values of the turtle (using the inspect tool) that you know is about to fail to see if there's anything odd about them.

Comment: When inspecting the turtle I could not find anything wrong with it. In the part of the programm where this failure occurs it is not asked for information from a turtle. That is why I assume the root cause is somewhere else. At least I think it is not any specific turtle causing the problem but probably the large number of turtles.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but because the names of the matrices are all very similar, and are, for me, very cryptic, I keep wondering whether there might be a typo in the name of a matrix in the source code.  Is that possible?  I know that the names are meaningful to you, and that's why you chose them.  If I were using these names, though, they would make typos more likely for me, even if I knew what the names meant.

Comment: At least in the code posted above there is no typo and I am pretty confident that there is none in the rest of the code. But at the moment I am reading through the program code to check that.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if matrix:get mxH2_r_seg1_tp column row != 0 [matrix:set mxH_r_seg1_tp column row (ln matrix:get mxH2_r_seg1_tp column row)]
```

sets an element of `mxH_r_seg1_tp` to the result of `ln` applied to an element of `mxH2_r_seg1_tp`.  If you take the logarithm of a number less than 1 and greater than 0, the result will be a negative number.  Is that what's happening?  You can use @JenB's advice to check whether `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` has elements < 1 just before the failure.

Note that repeatedly taking the logarithm of the result of taking a logarithm will eventually produce a number less than 1.  Perhaps it's also relevant that the first three lines of the posted code multiply matrix elements repeatedly, since repeated multiplication can generate numbers less than 1 as well.  Or perhaps the multiplications cause the matrix elements to increase in magnitude, while taking the log decreases their magnitude, and it takes many ticks before any element is < 1?  Since there are several matrices involved in repeated calculations, it's hard to know whether one of these factors might be relevant, but you will be able to check.

Comment: Matrix `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` contains negative values just before the error occurs. But normally there should not be any negative values in this matrix. If everything would work right, matrix `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` would contain only those items of `mx_r_seg1_tp` of which the logarithm should be taken. That is why `mx_r_seg1` is multiplied with `mxH1_av`. The latter is a matrix containing only 1 and 0 items. So by multiplying each item element wise of those two matrices I try to “delete” all items that should not be logarithmized.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is it `mx_r_seg1_tp` or `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` that inappropriately contains negative values?  In the code that you have posted, only the second of these is every modified, and only in the third line.  Or ar you're saying that `mx_r_seg1_tp` must be incorrect, because that would be what would cause `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` to be incorrect?  But nothing in the posted code changes `mxH2_r_seg1_tp`.  If that's where the problem is, then the posted code can't be the source of the problem (unless there's a serious implementation bug, as I consider in my latest comment on your question itself).

Comment: Matrix `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` is a partial copy of `mx_r_seg1_tp` and none of those two should contain any negative values. But as far as I understand the function `matrix:times-element-wise` correct those two matrices should not be linked anymore after the third line. So even if `mx_r_seg_tp` would be modified on purpose during the `while` loop, `mxH2_r_seg1_tp` should not be changed. In fact both are altered to the same values.

Comment: I understand `matrix:times-element-wise` the same way, and I did some simple tests to verify that its output is different from its input.  So this does sound to me like a bug in NetLogo or Java.  The fact that you have so many turtles, and the fact that the matrix extension is probably not very widely used might possibly be a reason why the bug hasn't been discovered before now.  Try adding `matrix:copy` before `matrix:times-element-wise`.  Then I would suggest bringing this up on the NetLogo development group or submitting an issue for the matrix extension.  More info in another comment.

Comment: Here's where to submit [matrix extension bug reports](https://github.com/NetLogo/Matrix-Extension/issues).  Here's the [NetLogo development](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netlogo-devel) Google group.  I strongly suggest, however, that you first try to reproduce the problem with a simpler program, maybe with just as many or more turtles if need be.  The clearer and more specific you can make the problem, the more helpful will responses be--for you as well as the NetLogo community.  I probably don't need to say this, but the extra work involved will worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on Jan final answer: I encountered a similar issue with NetLogo 5.1 and the new updated Matrix module. It seems that matrix:times-scalar will not only report the resulting matrix, but will also tamper the original one. This can be demonstrated using this code snippet (enter in Command Center):

```
(let m matrix:from-row-list [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]) (let m2 (matrix:times-scalar m -1)) (print m) (print m2)
```

Correct result (given by NetLogo 5.0.5) should be:

```
{{matrix:  [ [ 1 2 3 ][ 4 5 6 ] ]}}
{{matrix:  [ [ -1 -2 -3 ][ -4 -5 -6 ] ]}}
```

Wrong result (given by NetLogo 5.1 and 5.2RC3):

```
{{matrix:  [ [ -1 -2 -3 ][ -4 -5 -6 ] ]}}
{{matrix:  [ [ -1 -2 -3 ][ -4 -5 -6 ] ]}}
```

This is most probably a bug because matrix:times-scalar is defined as a reporter and not a procedure (ie: you cannot just do matrix:times-scalar m -1), and from the NetLogo documentation, reporter functions should report (return) their results without tampering the inputs.

Only matrix:times-scalar is affected. To workaround this issue, you can either use matrix:times (which supports scalars as input since NetLogo 5.1), or you can matrix:copy your matrix before using matrix:times-scalar, or you can use NetLogo 5.0.5 which is not affected by the issue (but new functions such as matrix:map won't be available).

For more info, see: https://github.com/NetLogo/Matrix-Extension/issues/12